# The PowerShell command for SPO365LinkSettings does not exist in the SharePoint farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, hybrid

I’m signing in to my Office 365 portal with my global administrator account from the development machine where I have a SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise farm upgraded to October CU 2015. In the SharePoint admin center I try to configure hybrid > Hybrid SharePoint Sites.

[image]

Clicking Next

[image]

[image]

Clicking Configure

[image]

[image]

And then the error occurs:

> ## SharePoint Hybrid Team Sites
>
> ## An error has occurred.
>
> One of the prerequisites is not met: the PowerShell command for
> SPO365LinkSettings does not exist in the SharePoint farm. Current
> SharePoint farm version is 15.0.4753.1000. As a prerequisite you
> should first upgrade to SharePoint 2013 with September 2015 product
> update and then re-run the wizard.
>
> Klicken Sie hier, um mehr über die neuesten Informationen zu den
> Voraussetzungen für SharePoint-Hybrid zu erfahren.

[image]

The link at the bottom is German, but I only got English, Swedish and Norwegian language packs installed (The second run gave an English result).

I already have the server patched to SharePoint 2015 CU, and I can’t find any Product Update for September 2015. Is this a wrong error message? Or is it something else I miss?

---

## Edit

All the following is in place (checked twice).

> **Prerequisites to using the Hybrid Picker:**
>
> - Be sure that an on-premises SharePoint Server 2013 farm has July PU or later properly installed (on-premises)
> - Make sure that ports 80 and 443 are open in the firewall for outbound communications (on-premises)
> - Log in to your SharePoint Server farm with an account that can access Central Administration as a Farm Administrator (on-premises)
> - When you must log in to Office 365, use an account who is Global Administrator (Office 365)
> - Accounts being synchronized must have at least one of the following properties: an e-mail address, a SIP address, or SMTP address.
>   (on-premises)
>
> **You need to run and configure these services:**
>
> - App Management Service
> - Subscription Settings Service
> - Search Service Application
> - User Profile Service
>
> on your on-premises SharePoint Server farm to avoid error messages
> while using the Hybrid Picker. In Central Administration, click Manage
> Services on server to check whether these services are in a started
> state.

Reference: [Hybrid picker in the SharePoint Online admin center](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Hybrid-picker-in-the-SharePoint-Online-admin-center-efce8417-c9bc-4a2c-ac9d-cce6c4e84a9c)

My guess is that this can't be done on SharePoint 2013 since the cmdlet `Get-SPO365LinkSettings` is only mentioned in combination with SharePoint 2016. See [What's new in SharePoint 2016?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2015/08/27/what-s-new-in-sharepoint-2016.aspx)

Comment: 15.0.4753.1000 represent to Sept CU, but you mentioned farm is upgraded to October 2015 CU. if you install the October CU, did you run the Config wizard?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I always run PSGONFIG after a SP CU install, on all servers. I'll update my question in a couple of hours to show that I've met all the prerequisites. My guess is that this can only be done on SP2016 since the Get-SPO365LinkSettings cmdlet is only referenced mention with 2016...

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Updated my question with prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back a year after trying this feature again, the result was the same in my SharePoint Server 2016 environment. The script halted at the exact same spot. Going forward I remembered that I have set up sites as Trusted Sites in internet explorer for getting SharePoint Designer to work properly. This was of course a long shot, but worth the try.

My trusted sites list now contains the following urls:

```
https://go.microsoft.com/
https://login.microsoftonline.com/
https://login.windows.net/
https://outlook.office.com/
https://outlook.office365.com/
https://portal.office.com/
https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/
https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com/
https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com/
https://www.microsoft.com/
```

And this time, without knowing why, it actually works. I now also have implemented Hybrid Search with splendid result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The product group released the delayed September 2015 Cumulative Update for the SharePoint 2013 product family. No other CU is required to fully patch SharePoint when using these “Uber packages”.

As this is a common question: Yes, September 2015 CU includes all fixes from September 2015 PU.

ATTENTION:

Be aware that all Updates for SharePoint 2013 require SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 to be installed first.

Please also have a look at the article that discusses how to properly patch a SharePoint 2013 farm which has Search enabled (see below).

Previous releases of the SharePoint Server 2013 cumulative update included both the executable and the .CAB file in the same self-extracting executable download. Because of the file size, the SharePoint Server 2013 package has been divided into several separate downloads. One contains the executable file, while the others contain the CAB file. All are necessary and must be placed in the same folder to successfully install the update. All are available by clicking the same Hotfix Download Available link in the KB article for the release.

This CU includes all SharePoint 2013 fixes (including all SharePoint 2013 security fixes) released since SP1. The CU does not include SP1. You need to install SP1 before installing this CU.

The KB articles for September CU should be available at the following locations in a couple of hours:

KB 2975894 – SharePoint Foundation 2013 September 2015 CU
KB 2986213 – SharePoint Server 2013 September 2015 CU
KB 2986195 – SharePoint Server 2013 with Project Server September 2015 CU
KB 3085487 – Office Web Apps Server 2013 September 2015 CU – This is also a security fix!
The Full Server Packages for September 2015 CU are available through the following links:

Download SharePoint Foundation 2013 September 2015 CU
Download SharePoint Server 2013 September 2015 CU
Download Project Server 2013 September 2015 CU
Download Office Web Apps Server 2013 September 2015 CU
Important: If your farm has been on a patch level lower than July 2015 CU: Unlike other CUs – after installing the September 2015 CU you need to run the SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard on each machine in the farm. 
If you don’t run PSCONFIG after installing September 2015 CU (on a farm which had a lower patch level than July 2015 CU) crawl might no longer work – so ensure to schedule a maintenance window when installing this CU which includes PSCONFIG runs.

See here for detail: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2015/07/15/important-psconfig-is-mandatory-for-July-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Be aware that the SharePoint Server 2013 CU contains the SharePoint Foundation CU. And the SharePoint Server 2013 with Project Server CU contains Project Server CU, SharePoint Server CU and SharePoint Foundation CU.

Answer (score 1):

This command is part of SharePoint 2016 but also available for sharepoint 2013 after the September CU 2015. Could you please check the below link and make sure you met all the prerequisite.

[Install and configure SharePoint Server 2013 hybrid](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn607322.aspx)

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work on SP 2013 nor on SP 2016 beta 2. I can however sync on premise AD with Office 365.